# apache camel multicast - performing aggregation in async manner

Tags: java, apache-camel, multicast

Suppose if I have a route in which I am multicasting the input to multiple processors.

**PRESENT BEHAVIOR:**

The console waits for some input from `System.in` stream, as soon as some input is given, the multicasting is done but the main thread waits until the aggregation is completed.

**EXPECTED BEHAVIOR:**

What I wanted to achieve is that the main thread should not wait for the aggreagation to complete but should return back and the main thread should start listening for new input from the console, as the route is `InOnly` type and not supposed to produce any output.

I tried using `parallelProcessing="true"` and `setExchangePattern pattern="InOnly"` in the route to affect the behavior but Multicast processor always waits for the aggregation task to complete and only then the main thread picks up other input from console.

```
<route>
      <from uri="stream:in?promptMessage=Enter something: "/>
      <setExchangePattern pattern="InOnly"/>
      <multicast parallelProcessing="true">
        <pipeline>
            <transform>
                <simple>${body.toUpperCase()}</simple>
            </transform>
            <!-- and then print to the console -->
            <to uri="stream:out"/>  
        </pipeline>
        <to uri="stream:out"/>
      </multicast>
</route>
```

Is this possible with multicast or is there some other way to achieve this?

Answer (score -2):

Take a look at the other EIPs that Apache Camel offers. The idea is not to use a single uber EIP, but that each of them offers a distinct functionality and that you can use them together to build your integration solutions.

- http://camel.apache.org/eip

For example you may take a look at wire tap, which allows to route a copy message independently from the original message.

- http://camel.apache.org/wire-tap.html